# When use CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm-light

Sometimes the UI is not updated and it is necessary to use a command to refresh commands. (RelayCommand). For example enable or disable a button.
I was there looking for how to solve the problem, I found this solution **CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()**.
This works, but I found this **"CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested () tries to validate all commands, Which is totally ineffective (and in your case slow) - on every change, you are asking every command to recheck its CanExecute ()"**
I've done some applications (with code-behind much like the one I have the problem) and I have this problem.
When the method execution ends, the buttons are not updated, I need click once on the UI.

```
...
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
...
...
private ICommand _downloadCommand;
        public ICommand DownloadCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _downloadCommand ?? (_downloadCommand = new RelayCommand(Download, () => IsEnabled));
            }
        }

        private ICommand _cancelDownloadCommand;
        public ICommand CancelDownloadCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _cancelDownloadCommand ?? (_cancelDownloadCommand = new RelayCommand(CancelDownload, () => IsEnabledCancel));
            }
        }

        private bool _isEnabled = true;
        private bool IsEnabled
        {
            get { return _isEnabled; }
            set
            {
                _isEnabled = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool _isEnabledCancel;
        private bool IsEnabledCancel
        {
            get { return _isEnabledCancel; }
            set
            {
                _isEnabledCancel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

private async void Download()
        {

            IsEnabled = false;

            IsEnabledCancel = true;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {

                ...
                ...
                ...
                ...
                ...

            });

            IsEnabled = true;

            IsEnabledCancel = false;

        }
```

.XAML

```
     <DockPanel Dock="Top">
        <Button Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding CancelDownloadCommand}" FontSize="20" 
                Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush4}" ToolTip="Cancel"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Images/48x48/Error.png" Height="48" Width="48"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}" FontSize="20" 
                Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush4}" ToolTip="Download"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Images/48x48/Download.png" Height="48" Width="48"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </DockPanel>
```